# Grab imdb poster image from search term using php

Tags: php, imdb

i would like to get the poster image url using php from imdb from a search term. For example i have the search term 21 Jump Street and i would like to get back the image ur or only the imdb movie url. With the below code i need only to retrieve the url of the movie from a search term

here is the code i have

```
<?php

    include("simple_html_dom.php");

//url to imdb page
$url = 'hereistheurliwanttogetfromsearch';

//get the page content
$imdb_content = file_get_contents($url);

$html = str_get_html($imdb_content);

$name = $html->find('title',0)->plaintext;

$director = $html->find('a[itemprop="director"]',0)->innertext;

$plot = $html->find('p[itemprop="description"]',0)->innertext;

$release_date = $html->find('time[itemprop="datePublished"]',0)->innertext;

$mpaa = $html->find('span[itemprop="contentRating"]',0)->innertext;

$run_time = $html->find('time[itemprop="duration"]',0)->innertext;

$img = $html->find('img[itemprop="image"]',0)->src;

$content = "";

//build content
$content.= '<h2>Film</h2><p>'.$name.'</p>';
$content.= '<h2>Director</h2><p>'.$director.'</p>';
$content.= '<h2>Plot</h2><p>'.$plot.'</p>';
$content.= '<h2>Release Date</h2><p>'.$release_date.'</p>';
$content.= '<h2>MPAA</h2><p>'.$mpaa.'</p>';
$content.= '<h2>Run Time</h2><p>'.$run_time.'</p>';
$content.= '<h2>Full Details</h2><p><a href="'.$url.'" rel="nofollow">'.$url.'</a></p>';
$content.= '<img src="'.$img.'" />';

echo $content;

?>
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i will post some code i found online. i  am newbie in php, ....i will edit and add the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the API that Kasper Mackenhauer Jacobsenless suggested here's a fuller answer:

```
$url = 'http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=21+jump+street';

$json_response = file_get_contents($url);
$object_response = json_decode($json_response);

if(!is_null($object_response) && isset($object_response->Poster)) {
        $poster_url = $object_response->Poster;
        echo $poster_url."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing with regex is bad but there is very little in this that could break. Its advised to use curl as its faster and you can mask your usergent.

The main problem with getting the image from a search is you first need to know the IMDB ID then you can load the page and rip the image url. Hope it helps

```
<?php 
//Is form posted
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $find = $_POST['find'];

    //Get Imdb code from search
    $source = file_get_curl('http://www.imdb.com/find?q='.urlencode(strtolower($find)).'&s=tt');
    if(preg_match('#/title/(.*?)/mediaindex#',$source,$match)){
        //Get main page for imdb id
        $source = file_get_curl('http://www.imdb.com/title/'.$match[1]);
        //Grab the first .jpg image, which is always the main poster
        if(preg_match('#<img src=\"(.*).jpg\"#',$source,$match)){
            $imdb=$match[1];
            //do somthing with image
            echo '<img src="'.$imdb.'" />';
        }
    }
}

//The curl function
function file_get_curl($url){
(function_exists('curl_init')) ? '' : die('cURL Must be installed');
$curl = curl_init();
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: ";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0 Firefox/5.0');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$html = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($status['http_code'] != 200){
    if($status['http_code'] == 301 || $status['http_code'] == 302) {
        list($header) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $html, 2);
        $matches = array();
        preg_match("/(Location:|URI:)[^(\n)]*/", $header, $matches);
        $url = trim(str_replace($matches[1],"",$matches[0]));
        $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
        return (isset($url_parsed))? file_get_curl($url):'';
    }
    return FALSE;
}else{
    return $html;
}
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
<p><input type="text" name="find" size="20"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```